# Can the J language be used as an effective alternative to Q/Kdb+?

Tags: programming

I hear a lot about Q/kdb+. I've never had the opportunity to use it for anything real but have played with it using their trial license and found it intriguing (if not somewhat mind warping). I've seen a few references to the [J language](http://www.jsoftware.com/) which is also a derivative of APL [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_%28programming_language%29) and have heard of at least one quant trader using it as a poor man's replacement for Q/kdb+.

Has anyone put J to use in the real world? Is it worth investing time and energy into to learn, especially if I'm not interested in investing the dollars required to get a kdb+ license? I suspect a lot of K/Q's value comes from the kdb+ database that underlies it. I'm not sure there is an equivalent for J, but I haven't performed an exhaustive search.

Interestingly enough, J recently went fully open source and is now hosted (not officially) on Github: https://github.com/openj/core.

**EDIT:** Assuming some folks here are familiar with J and Q/kdb+ but have not used J extensively in industry, what might be some major advantages or disadvantages of using J.

**EDIT 2:** J has a database solution in [JDB](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/JDB). One obvious follow-up which I also asked in a comment to @chrisaycock's answer below is how JDB might compare to kdb+ in terms of functionality.

Comment: That GitHub repo is from a fan, not an employee of J Software. The official source is [here](http://www.jsoftware.com/source.htm). And yeah, I've actually thought about cloning kdb+ for J precisely for the open-source crowd, though I'd have to get a boat-load of time before getting around to that.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I've updated the question to indicate that the Github is unofficial.

Comment: Maybe rather than cloning kdb+ totally it would be worth implementing J on an opensource datastore. I remember looking at this previously and coming to the conclusion that something like tokyo cabinet might fit the bill. 

That said I may be getting this totally wrong as I have had NO exposure to q/kdb+ and relied on what I could find online. (Yes you can get a trial version of kdb but my mind had wandered by the time I discovered the fact)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right that the database component is the main selling point of q/kdb+. Indeed, many Kx customers use kdb+ just for time-series data (and often just for tick history) and don't take advantage of the q language. So the first disadvantage to using J as-is would be to miss the reason most folks even bother with Kx: data storage.

Now of course you could clone the data storage for J, just as you could for any language. The really hard part is coming-up with your own version of the query and join routines found in `q.k`, that cryptic file that comes with the q software distribution.

Regarding [JDB](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/JDB), the biggest difference I can find is that it doesn't support partitioning. For example, kdb+ can split the column-mapped files into separate directories for each date. That means a query `select from quotes where date=2011.09.08` will cause kdb+ to jump directly to today's ticks. Taking that further, kdb+ supports threading to some degree (via `par.txt`) so that it can process multiple dates in parallel. And beyond the performance benefits, partitioning is practically required for really large tables anyway since the columns are memory-mapped at query time; there's no feasible way to do that for a multi-terabyte database without some selectivity.

The second disadvantage is that there aren't nearly as many finance shops that use J. Almost every big bank has a Kx license somewhere, so there's always an expert if needed. J doesn't have nearly that adoption.

Of course, J's main advantage now is that it's open source. And even before going open, J Software was more academic-friendly than Kx Systems, so there's more presence of J in the universities. Because of that, there seems to be more J examples in papers and on Project Euler than for either k or q.

Comment: How does kdb+ compare to J's JDB? This might also be a separate question all together I suppose.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

to add to chrisaycock's reply,

J has Jd database (comercial) now.  Its a purer vector language than q, but can be used with the same simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for an alternative to Q, try R.  It's a a great language for modeling and time series analysis.   For a DB, try cassandra, which supports partitioned data, high-speed access/queries.

Nice thing is that you can quickly produce compelling graphs and charts in R.

Also, R has a big community compared to J.   And it's all open source, with a strong, dynamic base of users...so you won't get stuck with code that no one can support or understand.